# В fail2ban за 2 дня накопилось огромное количество IP

Tags: isp, fail2ban

В fail2ban за 2 дня накопилось огромное количество IP. Это нормальная ситуация? Такое ощущение, что просто банит 70% посетителей.

Всего посетителей 1500 с 3х сайтов. Сервер VDS - ISP.

**Если это не нормально, то как это можно исправить?**

Прошу обратить внимание на количество, просто огромнейшее количество строк за 2 дня. Также обратите внимание на время. Был бы рад любой помощи. Спасибо.

[image: Скриншот лога]

Comment: А что мешает злоумышленникам использовать proxy и делать каждый запрос с нового ip?

Comment: Если на SSH стоит доступ только по ключу и отключен парольный вход, то волноваться особо не о чем. А так - ну пытаются взломать, да.

Comment: @Inventor То-есть такое огромнейшее количество это нормально для такого трафика?

Comment: @ГеннадийП У нас не отключен парольный вход, но там пароль из 12 символов сгенерированный, это же вполне нормальная защита?

Comment: @Sunrise Использование паролей при входе по SSH это вполне себе уязвимость. Советую переходить на ключи, это не сложно.